# if running fsck from live media do you still need to unmount target partition

Tags: server, live-usb, fsck, umount

I've been having issues with my ubuntu server.  Every day or two I'll lose the ability to remote connect to the server.  When I connect directly I see lots of repetitive error messages with long strings of numbers and letters.  I've also had busybox and readonly file system issues.  So I've been booting from live media and running:

```
sudo fsck -y /dev/nvme1n1p1

sudo fsck -y /dev/nvme1n1p2
```

on the partitions that have my operating system and boot efi.  Since I've been booting from live media usb to run fsck on the installed operating system partitions I haven't been unmounting the partitions before running fsck.  I'm wondering since I'm booting from live media (usb) and running fsck on the drive and partitions where the operating system is installed, do I still need to unmount the partitions before running fsck (ex. umount /dev/nvme1n1p1)?

when I try running

```
sudo umount /dev/nevme1n1p1
```

I get the message

```
umount: /dev/nvme1n1p1: not mounted.
```

I'm assuming that's because I'm running "sudo umount /dev/nvme1n1p1" using the operating system running from the live media usb stick.

if I run

```
sudo parted -l
```

I can see listed

```
Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 250GB
```

along with the two partitions for installed operating system and boot efi.

so my main question is again, if I'm running fsck -y /dev/nvme1n1p1 to clean up my previously installed operating system using live media, do I still have to unmount /dev/nvme1n1p1.  If so how do I do that with the live media usb?

Comment: Yes, it must be `umount`ed. Otherwise,  you have two copies of the partition metadata in play.

Comment: Only if it is mounted ... and it is not. The reason you have to boot from USB / live-media is that the normal os-disk then don't get mounted.

Comment: @SorenA thank you, that seems to be the same answer I got out of chatgpt.  I don't trust chatgpt so it's nice to have an expert opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of booting into a live disk is to access the partitions unmounted.  The typical reason you need a live disk to do this is that the partition you are trying to fix is the root partition and it has the OS on it, so you can't unmount it as long as the OS is running.

The act of rebooting the machine unmounts the partitions.  But if you boot into the OS on that partition, it will mount it as part of the boot process.

On the other hand, the only reason the partition would be mounted in the live disk is if:

- you manually mounted it with the mount command or by opening it in the file manager
- some automount thing found it and decided to automatically mount it

You can check what partitions are mounted with the `df` command.